# Cordova android URL.createObjectURL(blob) not working

Tags: android, ios, cordova, camera

I am building a cordova application and I need to retrieve a blob from an image file and use that as the src of an img tag. Right now the image is stored locally, but will be pulled from a database in the future. Everything is working as expected, but the source of the image is not being set when I use `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`, it seems the url is corrupt.

Here is my code:

```
      takePicture() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        const srcType = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
        const options = {
            // Some common settings are 20, 50, and 100
            quality: 10,
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            // In this app, dynamically set the picture source, Camera or photo gallery
            sourceType: srcType,
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
            mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
            allowEdit: true,
            correctOrientation: true, //Corrects Android orientation quirks
        };
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
            function cameraSuccess(imageUri) {
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
                    imageUri,
                    function success(fileEntry) {
                        fileEntry.file(
                            function(file) {
                                const reader = new FileReader();
                                reader.onloadend = function() {
                                    const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.result)], { type: 'image/png' });
                                    const elem = document.getElementById('img');
                                    elem.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                                };
                                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                            },
                            function(e) {
                                alert(e);
                            }
                        );
                    },
                    function() {}
                );
            },
            function cameraError(error) {
                alert('Unable to obtain picture: ' + error, 'app');
            },
            options
        );
```

If I remove this line of code: `elem.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);`

And replace it with this: `elem.src = imageUri;`

Everything works fine, so I know the image is being saved correctly. Is it possible that the image is to large, and therefore being rejected?

Answer (score -1):

OK, after doing some more troubleshooting, I figured out the problem was the  tag was missing the img-src directive. To fix this I simply added `img-src '*' data: blob: ;` to the  tag, and everything is working.

Note: Just adding `'*'` did not work. I also had to add `blob:` as well